# Selecting sample that maximizes correlation

Tags: r, optimization, correlation

I have an optimization problem I'm struggling to code in R. I have a panel dataset with each worker's weight and height observed twice.

```
worker weight height weight2 height2
1      120    60     125     60
2      152    55     156     66
3      222    55     100     20
```

I want to determine the maximum correlation between weight and height without regard for when the data was collected. For example, I want to determine if the correlation is stronger when I use worker 1's weight and height or worker 1's weight2 and height2, and so on for each worker. What is the best way to determine the sample that maximizes this correlation?

Comment: First, you should ask whether you should do this. This sounds very much like p-hacking. Or trying to maximize a finding by cherry-picking your data.

Comment: Second, you should ask whether you can do this. Depending on how many rows you have this can quickly become a very large problem. The number of permutations is the number of choices (2 in this case) to the power of the number of samples (2^n). For 3 rows you would have 8 combinations (111 112 121 122 211 212 221 222) to model. For 100 rows you would have over 1 Billion combinations to model. For 1000 rows you have 10^30 combinations to model. No small task.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some possible approaches. The first is using a global MINLP solver (not using R) and the second is demonstrating a GA (Genetic Algorithm) heuristic from R.

### Solve as non-convex MINLP

An MINLP (Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming) model for this problem can be:

```
 max cor(h,w)
 h[i] = height1[i]*(1-x[i]) + height2[i]*x[i]
 w[i] = weight1[i]*(1-x[i]) + weight2[i]*x[i]
 x[i] ∈ {0,1}
```

I.e. a value of `x[i]=0` selects the first observation and `x[i]=1` selects the second one.

This requires a global solver such as Baron, Antigone or Couenne.

Here is an example with Baron:

```
----     27 PARAMETER data  

        height1     weight1     height2     weight2

i1    67.433285  168.262871   67.445523  163.692389
i2    70.638374  174.437750   68.649190  160.084811
i3    71.317794  159.909672   69.503911  164.720010
i4    59.850261  145.704159   61.175728  142.708300
i5    65.341938  155.586984   68.483909  165.564991
i6    64.142009  154.335001   68.568683  166.169507
i7    67.030368  158.768813   65.780803  153.721717
i8    73.672863  175.126951   73.236515  164.704340
i9    65.203516  157.593587   63.279277  149.784500
i10   69.001848  160.063428   68.786656  162.278007
i11   64.455422  159.039195   63.930208  152.827710
i12   70.719334  164.885704   69.666096  157.356595
i13   65.688428  151.223468   63.614565  150.071072
i14   66.569252  160.978671   70.533320  160.722483
i15   78.417676  172.298652   80.070076  172.695207
i16   65.396154  158.234709   67.404942  158.310596
i17   62.504967  150.899428   61.000439  154.094647
i18   62.122630  150.024298   63.634554  153.644324
i19   70.598400  165.086523   72.999194  166.771223
i20   74.935107  170.820610   76.622182  169.013550
i21   63.233956  154.331546   60.372876  149.152520
i22   72.550105  173.961915   76.748649  167.462369
i23   74.086553  168.190867   75.433331  171.773607
i24   65.379648  163.577697   65.717553  160.134888
i25   64.003038  155.357607   67.301426  158.713710

----     68 VARIABLE x.L  select 1 or 2

i1  1.000000,    i2  1.000000,    i3  1.000000,    i8  1.000000,    i9  1.000000,    i11 1.000000,    i13 1.000000
i14 1.000000,    i16 1.000000,    i19 1.000000,    i21 1.000000,    i22 1.000000,    i23 1.000000,    i24 1.000000
i25 1.000000


----     68 VARIABLE z.L                   =     0.956452  objective

----     72 PARAMETER corr  

all1    0.868691,    all2    0.894532,    optimal 0.956452
```

Notes:

- The zeros in `x` are not printed
- The parameter `corr` displays the correlation for three cases: (a) when all `x[i]=0`, (b) when all `x[i]=1` and (c) for the optimal values of `x`.
- I ran this using GAMS/Baron (i.e. outside of R)

### Solve as non-convex MIQCP

With a bit of effort, we can reformulate our MINLP model into a non-convex quadratic model. This model can be solved with a solver like Gurobi (available under R). For more details see [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2020/10/maximum-correlation-global-minlp-vs-ga.html).

### Use a meta-heuristic

If we want to find just a good solution instead of a proven optimal solution, we can use a  meta-heuristic such as a genetic algorithm. Here is a trial with `ga` from the package `GA`:

```
> df <- read.table(text="
+ id      height1     weight1     height2     weight2
+ i1    67.433285  168.262871   67.445523  163.692389
+ i2    70.638374  174.437750   68.649190  160.084811
+ i3    71.317794  159.909672   69.503911  164.720010
+ i4    59.850261  145.704159   61.175728  142.708300
+ i5    65.341938  155.586984   68.483909  165.564991
+ i6    64.142009  154.335001   68.568683  166.169507
+ i7    67.030368  158.768813   65.780803  153.721717
+ i8    73.672863  175.126951   73.236515  164.704340
+ i9    65.203516  157.593587   63.279277  149.784500
+ i10   69.001848  160.063428   68.786656  162.278007
+ i11   64.455422  159.039195   63.930208  152.827710
+ i12   70.719334  164.885704   69.666096  157.356595
+ i13   65.688428  151.223468   63.614565  150.071072
+ i14   66.569252  160.978671   70.533320  160.722483
+ i15   78.417676  172.298652   80.070076  172.695207
+ i16   65.396154  158.234709   67.404942  158.310596
+ i17   62.504967  150.899428   61.000439  154.094647
+ i18   62.122630  150.024298   63.634554  153.644324
+ i19   70.598400  165.086523   72.999194  166.771223
+ i20   74.935107  170.820610   76.622182  169.013550
+ i21   63.233956  154.331546   60.372876  149.152520
+ i22   72.550105  173.961915   76.748649  167.462369
+ i23   74.086553  168.190867   75.433331  171.773607
+ i24   65.379648  163.577697   65.717553  160.134888
+ i25   64.003038  155.357607   67.301426  158.713710
+ ", header=T)
> 
> #
> # print obvious cases 
> #
> cor(df$weight1,df$height1)
[1] 0.8686908
> cor(df$weight2,df$height2)
[1] 0.894532
> 
> #
> # fitness function
> #
> f <- function(x) {
+   w <- df$weight1*(1-x) + df$weight2*x
+   h <- df$height1*(1-x) + df$height2*x
+   cor(w,h) 
+ }
> 
> library(GA)
> res <- ga(type=c("binary"),fitness=f,nBits=25,seed=123)
GA | iter = 1 | Mean = 0.8709318 | Best = 0.9237155
GA | iter = 2 | Mean = 0.8742004 | Best = 0.9237155
GA | iter = 3 | Mean = 0.8736450 | Best = 0.9237155
GA | iter = 4 | Mean = 0.8742228 | Best = 0.9384788
GA | iter = 5 | Mean = 0.8746517 | Best = 0.9384788
GA | iter = 6 | Mean = 0.8792048 | Best = 0.9486227
GA | iter = 7 | Mean = 0.8844841 | Best = 0.9486227
GA | iter = 8 | Mean = 0.8816874 | Best = 0.9486227
GA | iter = 9 | Mean = 0.8805522 | Best = 0.9486227
GA | iter = 10 | Mean = 0.8820974 | Best = 0.9486227
GA | iter = 11 | Mean = 0.8859074 | Best = 0.9486227
GA | iter = 12 | Mean = 0.8956467 | Best = 0.9486227
GA | iter = 13 | Mean = 0.8989140 | Best = 0.9486227
GA | iter = 14 | Mean = 0.9069327 | Best = 0.9486227
GA | iter = 15 | Mean = 0.9078787 | Best = 0.9486227
GA | iter = 16 | Mean = 0.9069163 | Best = 0.9489443
GA | iter = 17 | Mean = 0.9104712 | Best = 0.9489443
GA | iter = 18 | Mean = 0.9169900 | Best = 0.9489443
GA | iter = 19 | Mean = 0.9175285 | Best = 0.9489443
GA | iter = 20 | Mean = 0.9207076 | Best = 0.9489443
GA | iter = 21 | Mean = 0.9210288 | Best = 0.9489443
GA | iter = 22 | Mean = 0.9206928 | Best = 0.9489443
GA | iter = 23 | Mean = 0.9210399 | Best = 0.9489443
GA | iter = 24 | Mean = 0.9208985 | Best = 0.9489443
GA | iter = 25 | Mean = 0.9183778 | Best = 0.9511446
GA | iter = 26 | Mean = 0.9217391 | Best = 0.9511446
GA | iter = 27 | Mean = 0.9274271 | Best = 0.9522764
GA | iter = 28 | Mean = 0.9271156 | Best = 0.9522764
GA | iter = 29 | Mean = 0.9275347 | Best = 0.9522764
GA | iter = 30 | Mean = 0.9278315 | Best = 0.9522764
GA | iter = 31 | Mean = 0.9300289 | Best = 0.9522764
GA | iter = 32 | Mean = 0.9306409 | Best = 0.9528777
GA | iter = 33 | Mean = 0.9309087 | Best = 0.9528777
GA | iter = 34 | Mean = 0.9327691 | Best = 0.9528777
GA | iter = 35 | Mean = 0.9309344 | Best = 0.9549574
GA | iter = 36 | Mean = 0.9341977 | Best = 0.9549574
GA | iter = 37 | Mean = 0.9374437 | Best = 0.9559043
GA | iter = 38 | Mean = 0.9394410 | Best = 0.9559043
GA | iter = 39 | Mean = 0.9405482 | Best = 0.9559043
GA | iter = 40 | Mean = 0.9432749 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 41 | Mean = 0.9441814 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 42 | Mean = 0.9458232 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 43 | Mean = 0.9469625 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 44 | Mean = 0.9462313 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 45 | Mean = 0.9449716 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 46 | Mean = 0.9444071 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 47 | Mean = 0.9437149 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 48 | Mean = 0.9446355 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 49 | Mean = 0.9455424 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 50 | Mean = 0.9456497 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 51 | Mean = 0.9461382 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 52 | Mean = 0.9444960 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 53 | Mean = 0.9434671 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 54 | Mean = 0.9451851 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 55 | Mean = 0.9481903 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 56 | Mean = 0.9477778 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 57 | Mean = 0.9481829 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 58 | Mean = 0.9490952 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 59 | Mean = 0.9505670 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 60 | Mean = 0.9499329 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 61 | Mean = 0.9509299 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 62 | Mean = 0.9505341 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 63 | Mean = 0.9519624 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 64 | Mean = 0.9518618 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 65 | Mean = 0.9523598 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 66 | Mean = 0.9516766 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 67 | Mean = 0.9521926 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 68 | Mean = 0.9524419 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 69 | Mean = 0.9532865 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 70 | Mean = 0.9535871 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 71 | Mean = 0.9536049 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 72 | Mean = 0.9534035 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 73 | Mean = 0.9532859 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 74 | Mean = 0.9521064 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 75 | Mean = 0.9534997 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 76 | Mean = 0.9539987 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 77 | Mean = 0.9536670 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 78 | Mean = 0.9526224 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 79 | Mean = 0.9531871 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 80 | Mean = 0.9527495 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 81 | Mean = 0.9526061 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 82 | Mean = 0.9525577 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 83 | Mean = 0.9525084 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 84 | Mean = 0.9519052 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 85 | Mean = 0.9518549 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 86 | Mean = 0.9511299 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 87 | Mean = 0.9505129 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 88 | Mean = 0.9518203 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 89 | Mean = 0.9537234 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 90 | Mean = 0.9531017 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 91 | Mean = 0.9514525 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 92 | Mean = 0.9505517 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 93 | Mean = 0.9524752 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 94 | Mean = 0.9533879 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 95 | Mean = 0.9519166 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 96 | Mean = 0.9524416 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 97 | Mean = 0.9526676 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 98 | Mean = 0.9523745 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 99 | Mean = 0.9523710 | Best = 0.9564515
GA | iter = 100 | Mean = 0.9519255 | Best = 0.9564515
> res@solution
     x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11 x12 x13 x14 x15 x16 x17 x18 x19 x20 x21 x22 x23 x24 x25
[1,]  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1
> res@fitnessValue
[1] 0.9564515
```

This actually finds the optimal solution for this small data set.

### Conclusion

The optimally selected data that maximizes the Pearson correlation coefficient is:

```
----     92 PARAMETER result  selected observations

        height1     weight1     height2     weight2

i1                            67.445523  163.692389
i2                            68.649190  160.084811
i3                            69.503911  164.720010
i4    59.850261  145.704159
i5    65.341938  155.586984
i6    64.142009  154.335001
i7    67.030368  158.768813
i8                            73.236515  164.704340
i9                            63.279277  149.784500
i10   69.001848  160.063428
i11                           63.930208  152.827710
i12   70.719334  164.885704
i13                           63.614565  150.071072
i14                           70.533320  160.722483
i15   78.417676  172.298652
i16                           67.404942  158.310596
i17   62.504967  150.899428
i18   62.122630  150.024298
i19                           72.999194  166.771223
i20   74.935107  170.820610
i21                           60.372876  149.152520
i22                           76.748649  167.462369
i23                           75.433331  171.773607
i24                           65.717553  160.134888
i25                           67.301426  158.713710
```